# Counting the permuted forms of a list with repeated members under a permutation group

Tags: permutation, group-theory

```
DeleteDuplicates[Permute[{g, g, g, g, g, e, r}, AlternatingGroup[7]]]
```

How to count number of lists automatically?

Comment: Would you explain more?

Comment: There is nothing built-in to count restricted permutations of this type.

Comment: If all you want is the count, use `Multinomial`. `Multinomial[5,1,1]                                                     

Out[18]= 42`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define your function and my proposal:

```
f1[l_, gr_] := Length@DeleteDuplicates@Permute[l, gr@Length@l]
f2[l_, gr_] := GroupOrder@gr@Length@l /
               GroupOrder@GroupSetwiseStabilizer[gr@Length@l, {l}, Permute]
```

`f2` isn't always faster than `f1`,but can calculate things where `f1` fails due to memory constraints. For example:

```
Timing@f1[{a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, b, b, c, c}, AlternatingGroup]
```

> Permute::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.

While:

```
Timing@f2[{a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, b, b, c, c}, AlternatingGroup]
(*
 {2.265625, 2970}
*)
```

Comment: I think ... Length@DeleteDuplicates[Permute[{g, g, g, g, g, e, r}, AlternatingGroup[7]]] is fine to get it.

Comment: @santosh Sorry.What do you mean?

Comment: I just want to count the number of permutations.

Comment: @santosh `f1` (your way) and `f2` (my function) both count that. But `f2` works for a larger set of lists (and larger lists). Also, it's faster in many cases.

Comment: ok thanks...I got it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the number of permutations you want, wouldn't it be easier to just use factorials? Please let me know if I'm missing something, but I think you could compute it as follows:

Suppose you have a list $\ell$ of $m$ entries containing $k\leq m$ distinct elements and let $n_k$ be the number of occurrences of the $k$-th element. For instance, suppose our list is
$$
    \ell\ =\ (a_1, a_2, a_2, a_3, a_3, a_3, a_3, a_3)
$$
In this case, $m=8$, $k=3$, $n_1=1$, $n_2=2$, $n_3=5$.

The number of permutations is computed from $m$ and the $n_i$'s as:
$$
    \#\text{perms}\ =\ \frac{m!}{n_1!\ \cdots\ n_k!}
$$
This is implemented in Mathematica by the `Multinomial` function. For instance, the above example is written as:

```
perms[list_]:= Multinomial @@ Tally[list][[All,2]]
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this improve performance immensely?

Comment: Hi! I think you missed an important part of the question. The title says _"under a permutation group"_ :)

Comment: Ah, I see.. thanks!